# Homeomorphic extension to totally disconnected sets

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

Dear Mathoverflow Community,

I am looking for a reference for the following topological fact:

**Fact**

Let $E$ and $F$ be two totally disconnected compact subsets of the plane (can assume perfect if you want). Then every homeomorphism $f: S^2 \setminus E \to S^2 \setminus F$ extends to a homeomorphism of $S^2$ onto itself.

Thank you,
Malik

Comment: For the perfect case, i.e. for embeddings of the Cantor set in $\mathbb R^2$, there might be some information in Moise's book "Geometric topology in dimensions 2 and 3".

Comment: It's false: just take $E=F$ to be $\{0\}$ and define $f(x)=x/\|x\|^2$. However it's true with the plane replaced by the 2-sphere, just because then the embedding into sphere is the end compactification.

Comment: @YCor Right, sorry, I meant the sphere.